# custom error in web config not works on server

Tags: asp.net, web.config-transform

I have an application, I used a custom error in the web.config. The problem is that when I test it on local host it's work properly , but when I deploy it on the server its not working. Below is my web.config custom error method that I am using on server web.config file.

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx?type=error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx?type=404"/>
</customErrors>
```

[image: Folder Structure of my application]

Comment: Does the website work OK on the server, other than the custom error not being shown?

Comment: @LeonBambrick , thanks for your comment yes the website is working ok only my custom error is not wroking properly

Comment: Please check that the version of .net on the server is the same as you are expecting.

Comment: @LeonBambrick the problem is that when user type abcd then its not displaying the open the error.aspx page , and i wants this , can you please help me